# JDI:How to iterate over HashMap

Tags: java, jdi

I get through JDI to get `com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference` is type `java.util.HashMap`,then i get filed  value "entrySet" ,why it is always null?
How can i  iterate over HashMap keyValues with java debug api?

```
public static void displayVariables(LocatableEvent event) throws IncompatibleThreadStateException, AbsentInformationException {
        StackFrame stackFrame = event.thread().frame(0);
        for (LocalVariable visibleVariable : stackFrame.visibleVariables()) {
            Value value = stackFrame.getValue(visibleVariable);
            if(value instanceof ObjectReference){
                ObjectReference objectReference = (ObjectReference) value;//is type java.util.HashMap
                Field entrySet = objectReference.referenceType().fieldByName("entrySet");// is java.util.HashMap.entrySet
                Value entrySetValue = objectReference.getValue(entrySet);// is null
                System.out.println(entrySet);

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (T key : hashMap.keySet()) {
    V value = hashMap.get(key);
    // rest of your code here
} // Can you get to where you need to go from here?
```

Assuming hashMap is of type HashMap<T, V>.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapConfig.forEach((k, v) -> {

});
```